# Attaching Multiple Files to an email in VB

Tags: vb6, email-attachments

I would like to add all excel files in a folder to an email with the following code:

```
Dim fs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
MItem.Display
With MItem
.Bcc = EmailAddr
.Subject = Subj
.Body = Msg
For Each File In fs.GetFolder(CurDir&"Final").Files
    If fs.GetExtensionName(File) = "xlsx" Then
    .Attachments.Add File
    End If
Next 
.Importance = 2
.Send
End With


Set MItem = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

However, I am getting error "Object doesn't support this property or method.

While as I attach individual files it's working.

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Give file path like this .Attachments.Add File.Path and try

Comment: Many thanks Balasubramaniyan! It did work!!